# Referring to outer scope from python class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, module, scope

I have a (simplified) module, something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

__outerVar = {<dict stuff>}

class Editor(tk.Frame):
...
    def _insideFunction(self):
        for p in __outerVar.keys():
            <do stuff>
```

I'm getting a `NameError: name '_Editor__outerVar' is not defined` on the use of `__outerVar` when I try to instantiate Editor.  I tried putting "`global __outerVar`" at the top of `insideFunction`, even though I'm not writing to `__outerVar`, same error.

I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding some python scope rule here.  Help?

py 3.5

Comment: Python name mangling at work. Why not just `outerVar` and access it as `outerVar` in your class?

Comment: I thought the _ and __ were only convention, indicating, essentially, protected and private variables.  I was not aware of said name mangling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python replaces any names preceded by a double underscore `__` in order to simulate 'private attributes'. In essence `__name` becomes `_classname__name`. This, called name mangling, happens only within classes as documented [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.

The solution is don't use `__name` names, using something like `_name` or just `name` suffices.

As an addendum, in [`PEP 8 -- Method Names and Instance Variables`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) it states:

> Python mangles these names with the class name: if class `Foo` has an attribute named `__a` , it cannot be accessed by `Foo.__a` . (An insistent user could still gain access by calling `Foo._Foo__a`.) *Generally, double leading underscores should be used only to avoid name conflicts with attributes in classes designed to be subclassed.*

So, unless you're designing for cases were subclass name clashing might be issue, don't use double leading underscores.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing name mangling in effect.  From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private):

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. **This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.**

As far as I can think, the only way around this is to rename the `__outerVar` in the global scope to something that doesn't start with double underscores.